# Is there a callback in Dropbox API when file upload (sync) starts?

Tags: api, file-upload, callback, dropbox

I am creating a web service that mashes up Dropbox, Soundcloud and Wordpress.

I need a callback when user places a file in his Dropbox folder so that I can update the browser user interface. Since it is possible to ask for a download link locally before a file is completely synced, I naturally expect it to be possible to get a callback when file sync has started on a file-by-file basis.

However according to what I experienced /delta only shows files that have finished syncing.

Is there a way to know when file sync starts? If it is not possible via Core API, could it be possible with a small client applet (java or something)?

Answer (score 1):

The Dropbox API doesn't currently expose any notion of a pending upload or file sync status. It can only return information about files that have finished uploading.

Likewise, even with a client app running on the same OS, there currently isn't an interface for communicating with the official Dropbox desktop client to get this information.